# reading data from files, file name as input

Tags: c++

I am writing a program which reads data from different files, which are given as input strings, and stores them into a vector of vectors. The problem I am not able to debug the loop which reads different files. I have closed the ifstream object, cleared the string using empty function... but still it just terminates when i give second file name as input.

I am copying the code for your perusal. It is a function called by another another function. Transposectr transposes a matrix.

## code:

```
vector<vector<float> > store1,store2;
ifstream bb;

string my_string;

float carrier;
vector<float> buffer;

cout<<"enter the file name"<<endl;
getline(cin,my_string);

while (my_string!="end")
{

    bb.open(my_string.c_str());
    while (!bb.eof())
    {
        bb >> carrier;

        if (bb.peek() == '\n' || bb.eof() )
        {
            buffer.push_back(carrier);
            store1.push_back(buffer);
            buffer.clear();
        }

        else
        {
            buffer.push_back(carrier);
        }

    
    }

    bb.close();
    buffer.clear();
    transposectr1(store1);
    storex.push_back(store1[1]);
    storey.push_back(store1[0]);
    store1.clear();
    my_string.empty();
    cout<<"done reading the file"<<endl;
    cout<<"enter the file name"<<endl;
    getline(cin,my_string);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm really not clear what you are trying to do. But I have one golden ruile when it comes to using istreams:

**Never use the eof() function!**

It almost certainly does not do what you think it does. Instead you should test if a read operation succeeded.

```
int x;

while( in >> x ) {
   // I read something successfully
}
```

You might also want to avoid peek() too. Try re-writing your code with this advice in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
bb.clear();
```

after the bb.close() you may get the right thing. bb.close() doesn't reset the cursor I think.

Answer (score 0):

Neil Butterworth is right

> Never use the eof() function!

[This link](http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/io/eof) explains why.

Comment: thanks!
But it worked. There was a bug in clearing the file name and am using cin to get file name now. Earlier i was using getline. I dunno why it didn work earlier..
Thanks for responding though.

Warm Regards
Saurabh 
India